# changing the gap between items in navbar relative to screen size

Tags: css

I want to close the gap between items in a navbar from 60px to 20px relative to the screen width. As the user decreases the screen width from 1065px to 905px I want the gap between nav items to decrease from 60px to 20px linearly and relative to the screen size reduction.

```
    <header class="header">

            <a href="#" class="logo">
                <img src="type2.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
            </a>

            <nav class="nav">

                <ul class="nav_list">
                    <li class="nav_item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Service</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Supply</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_link">Sale</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav_item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav_btn">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>

    </header>
```

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    /* It makes the body a flex container */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("4857385.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 91, 127, 0.75);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 30px;
}


.logo_img {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px; 
    
}

.nav_list {
    display: flex; 
    column-gap: 60px;
}

.nav_link {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .3s;
}


.nav_link:hover {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #ffee10;
}

.nav_btn {
    color: rgba(0, 91, 127, 1);
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7px 18px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav_btn:hover {
    color: #001F3F;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #ffee10;

}

@media (max-width: 1115px) {
    .header {
        padding: 0 5px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1065px) and (min-width: 905px) {

    /* I don't know what to do */
}

@media (max-width: 905px) {
    .header {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    }
    .nav_list {
        column-gap: 52px;
    }
}
```

I tried gap, column-gap, margin-right with this formula : calc(60px - 2px * (100vw - 905px) / 160);
but it didn't work at all

Comment: You can't do that in `px`. You need to use relative sizes like `vw` or `%` etc.

Comment: Why not use `space-between` instead of a fixed pixel gap?

Comment: @Paulie_D how do you reduce the gap between nav items linearly relative to screen width as the screen width reduces using space-between? what is your solution?

Comment: The nav items will be spaced evenly across whatever space is available. If that space reduces, the gap will reduce accordingly. Try it.